# npm ERR! missing script: json:

Tags: npm, json-server

I'm getting this error when I run npm run json: server.

npm ERR! missing script: json:

when I open the log file, this is what it says:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'json:',
1 verbose cli   'server' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.2.1
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: json:
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:402:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:357:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:400:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:348:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16
4 verbose stack     at tryToString (fs.js:513:3)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\IanP\Documents\GitHub\JSONSERVER
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
7 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "json:" "server"
8 verbose node v8.2.1
9 verbose npm  v5.5.1
10 error missing script: json:
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

My package.json has the following

```
   {
  "name": "jsonserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Fake REST API for testing",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "json:server": "json-server --watch db.json" 
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.12.1"
  }
}
```

I did not modify anything since it's last successful run. When I was starting to work the following day, suddenly the error.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the "json:server" in scripts to any of the JSON verified characters.

`:` are generally used to separate key-value pair.
Even in the log it's pointing out to the same (see verbose line 7).
`7 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\IanP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "json:" "server"`

So, it would be good idea to replace "json:server" with "json-server" or using camel-Case insted like "jsonServer".

Hope this helps.